# nslookup and tracert inconsistencies

Tags: windows, networking, windows-7, virtual-machines, virtualbox

In a Windows 7 VirtualBox guest with NAT and an OpenVPN connection issued by the host, `nslookup` and `tracert` behave differently w.r.t. name resolution:

- `nslookup hostname` works, using `10.0.2.3` as DNS server
- `tracert hostname` cannot resolve hostname
- `tracert fqdn` cannot resolve fqdn
- `tracert ip-address` works and shows host name, routing via `10.0.2.2` -> `10.0.3.1` -> target
- `traceroute hostname` works in the host, routing directly via `10.0.3.1` -> target

The host I am trying to reach is within the network where I dial in using OpenVPN. Name resolution works well for globally reachable hosts.

What could be the reason? How can I find out? I already tried disabling IPv6 for the network connection, and disabling firewall on both host and guest, and changing network type to "Bridged" in VirtualBox.

I have the following setup:

- Ubuntu 13.04 x64 host
- VirtualBox `4.2.10-dfsg-0ubuntu2.1`

  - Intel PRO/1000 virtual network adapter attached to NAT
  - Windows 7 x86 guest, fully patched
- OpenVPN connection issued by the host
- Same host name in Windows 7 guest and Ubuntu 13.04 host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution in [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/330409/946850):

> [Put] a single entry reading "." in the *"Append these DNS suffixes (in order)"* in the *"Advanced TCP/IP settings"* dialog.

Looks like `tracert` and friends by default tries some non-DNS protocol first, which fails in my setup.